# Access text file in parallel resources folder using relative path

Tags: java, text-files, javafx-8, classloader, relative-path

Hello and thank you for taking the time to look at this question.

I am having trouble accessing a text file in a folder parallel to my src folder (see below for structure).

The closest I have found to an explanation is here: https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/cit597-2006/Pages/finding-files.html
and I have come across many similar questions but none from which I can infer the answer to this one unfortunately.

I know I could use absolute paths but I want to make sure that this software will work on other people's computers so that's a no-go. Therefore, I am trying to get it to work with relative paths.

As a bonus, it is suggested here: https://coderanch.com/t/464197/java/java/Reading-files-directory-giving-relative that in order for this code to work inside a JAR file, I'll have to use getResourceAsStream(). Could anyone advise?

I am trying to access Recipes.txt from within RecipeReader.java, here is my code so far:

```
        Class thisClass = this.getClass();
        ClassLoader loader = thisClass.getClassLoader();
        URL recipeFileURL = loader.getResource("Recipes.txt");
        String path = recipeFileURL.getPath();
        path.replaceAll("%20",  " ");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
```

and similarly to write to the same file:

```
        Class thisClass = this.getClass();
        ClassLoader loader = thisClass.getClassLoader();
        URL recipeFileURL = loader.getResource("Recipes.txt");
        String path = recipeFileURL.getPath();
        path.replaceAll("%20",  " ");
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path));
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Robin

[image: Eclipse Tree View]

Answer (score 5):

If the files are bundled inside your jar file, then they aren't files anymore: the file system doesn't contain these files at runtime, since they're embedded in the jar file. So you may **NOT** use file IO to read them. `new FileReader(path)` doesn't make sense.

It also seems that you want to modify the contents of those resources. That is definitely not possible if the resources are embedded in the jar file.

So you need to think about what you really want to do, and how you will provide the application to your end users and install it.

If the files contain static, read-only resources needed by the application, then they should be bundled in the jar file, and read using the ClassLoader.

If the files are data, that must be read and saved by the application, just like a text editor would do, then it probably doesn't make sense to provide them with the application: just ask the user where to load/save the files.

If they are preferences that need to be loaded and saved transparently by the application, then you could load and save them from/to a .myApp.prefs file located in the user's home directory, for example.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for sharing that. It seems like my original question is rather redundant, given that the user can just select a location where they would like to store the files. However, this may be a little bit of a silly question, but how would you save the file path which the user enters into the java program when it is already compiled? It seems a little chicken and egg as you would have to have an editable file at a location from which you read the location of your other editable file! Thank you very much for your time and knowledge, it is greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you please explain what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the way you would do it is put your resource in a folder which matches the package name of the class that will load it.

For example, you would have this:

```
package com.robhartley.application;

public class ResourceLoader {
    public List<Recipe> loadRecipes() {
         InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("Recipes.txt");
         // ...
    }
}
```

with the following file in your project: `resources/com/robhartley/application/Recipes.txt`.